# Element head is missing a required instance of child element title

Tags: html, validation

hey so I have the error where I am missing a title inside of my head. But you can see from the code that I have one there. It was all hand written too so I shouldn't have any problems with copy paste etc...

heres the code:

```
<head>
<style type = "text/css">
    body {
        background-image: url("background.jpg");
        color: white;
         }
<title>Dariean Drewes - DIGI 220 Labs Standard and Advanced</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Dariean Drewes - DIGI 220 Labs</h1>
<h2>About Me</h2>
<p> I am a second year Digital Media student. I like playing video games and running. I also like designing websites as it is a lot of fun.</p>
<p> I am hoping to expand my skills in website development. I hope that by the end of this course that I can create and design my very own website and have the foundational skills necessary in order to get my feet went in my chosen field.</p>
<img src="self-portrait.jpg" alt="Self Portrait" height="600" width="400"> 
<p>Looking for more than your average joe? Looking for someone with stylish hair and bright blue eyes? Looking for someone who can design a webpage and put in text and pictures? WELL LOOK NO FARTHER! Hi! My name is Dariean Drewes and I am a currently aspiring Digital artist! I work with HTML 5 and CSS in order to:bring your beautiful webpages that showcase my skills. I am in my Second Year of Schooling and am undergoing rigorous studies that test my abilities daily. Everyday I will bring something new to your team whether it is; </p>
<ol>
    <li>technical expertise</li>
    <li>artistic detail</li>
    <li>or simply the hard work and man hours to make that deadline.</li>

</ol>
<p>So if your looking for a talented employee that has the right stuff you have come to the right place!</p>
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: meta and title tags should be outside of style tag

Answer (score 1):

try changing to this..

```
 <head>
    <title>Dariean Drewes - DIGI 220 Labs Standard and Advanced</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <style type = "text/css">
        body {
            background-image: url("background.jpg");
            color: white;
             }                
    </style>
    </head>
```